# Checking string containing item from table

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
if FirstName:GetValue() == ""
or table.HasValue( Blocked, string.lower(FirstName:GetValue())) then
-- Checks if the name contains any "bad" words, or nothing was typed in.
    FirstNameCHECK = false
    text4:SetText("Bad Name")
    text4:SetColor(Color(255,0,0,255))
else
    FirstNameCHECK = true
    text4:SetText("Good Name")
    text4:SetColor(Color(0,255,0,255))
end
```

This code currently checks for the string being exactly the same as an entry in a table.

How would I be able to change this code so it checks if the string inserted (FirstName variable) contains one of the entries from the table?

Comment: Take a look at [`string.find`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.find), and use it with all your banned patterns once each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inefficient solution would be to iterate over the table and call `string.find` on each element. This approach can get quite slow for very large tables, as you have to inspect every element, but will probably be perfectly fine unless you are dealing with really big datasets.

A more clever approach would be to use nested tables indexed by substrings. For instance, you could have a root table with indices `a` to `z`. You index into that table with the first letter of your word and you get back another table of the same structure. This one you index with the second letter and so on until you either find no more table at the letter you are checking, or you arrived at the end of the word. In the latter case, you might need an additional unique entry in the table that indicates whether the exact word you were looking up is in the table (as there are no more letters, you need to be able to check this somehow).

This approach has several disadvantages. Building the table can be very memory intensive and performing the check might very well be slower than the naive approach for smaller tables. Also manipulating the lookup table is not that straightforward (think about removing a word from it for instance). So this kind of structure is really only useful for performing the lookup and you should stick with normal tables for other tasks.

For example, you might want to maintain in the lookup table a list of references to entries in the real data table which allow you to get from a particular prefix string all matching entries in the data table.

Comment: As a newbie to LUA. Will I be able to have a sample of the code for the inefficient solution. The table isn't that large...

Answer (score 0):

Made a solution for those kind of stuff in some other question (works with multi dimensional tables) - [Loop until find 2 specific values in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463078/loop-until-find-2-specific-values-in-a-table/27463353#27463353)

```
function MultiTableSearch(input,value,case,index_check)
    if (input and type(input) == 'table') then
        if (type(value) == 'table' and value == input) then
            return true;
        end
        for key,object in pairs(input) do
            if (index_check) then
                if (case and type(input)=='string' and type(key)=='string') then
                    if (value:lower() == key:lower()) then -- to avoid exit the loop
                        return true;
                    end
                else
                    if (key == value) then
                        return true
                    elseif(type(object)=='table') then
                        return MultiTableSearch(object,value,case,index_check)
                    end
                end
            else
                if (case and type(value)=='string' and type(object) == 'string') then
                    if (value:lower() == object:lower()) then
                        return true;
                    end
                elseif(type(object)=='table') then
                    if (value == object) then
                        return true;
                    else
                        return MultiTableSearch(object,value,case)
                    end
                else
                    if (object == value) then
                        return true;
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return false;
end
```

and to use call this

```
MultiTableSearch(blocked,FirstName:GetValue(),true) -- table,name,case(true to ignore case)
```